# How to receive call when app is not running?

Tags: ios, swift, twilio, voip, callkit

The bug scenario for User 2:

User 1 is calling User 2

iOS App is in termination state (killed)

Call UI is not shown

Call rejected by User 1

Now open app & call is receiving (CallKit UI shown) however call is terminated by User 1

The call is working in
Foreground state
Background state

Not working in
Killed state

Capability: Background modes, Audio, airplay, VoIP, Background fetch, Remote notifications

I face this issue every time, also I'm unable to test calls in development mode. For testing, I have to make an AdHoc build & then I can test. In development, mode calls are not received in any scenario.

I want to receive call-in killed state also.

Versions:
TwilioVoice: 6.3.1, TwilioVideo: 5.0

iOS versions: >15.0, iOS devices: Any

Code:

```
var voipRegistry = PKPushRegistry.init(queue: DispatchQueue.main)


func pushRegistry(_ registry: PKPushRegistry, didUpdate credentials: PKPushCredentials, for type: PKPushType) {

}
```

Comment: In "Killed" state, you will receive push notification using PushKit and then you need to init IncomingCall of CallKit so that it can show you UI even when app is in killed state. You have to handle push notifications

Comment: Have you found a solution yet?